# Finding the max random number

Tags: c++

I am instructed to find the max number generated from a 2D array: arr[10][10]. Is this code correct? To me its seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int maxArray(int arr[][10], int rcap, int ccap) {
    int max = arr[10][10]; srand(time(0));
    for (int r=0; r < rcap; r++)
        for(int c=0; c < ccap; c++)
            if(arr[r][c] > max) max = (rand()%100)+100;

    return max;
}

int main() {
    int a[10][10];
    cout << maxArray (a,10,10) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't access arr[10][10]. The maximum element is arr[9][9]. And you are using the values contained in `a` without first initializing it. This is bad! Written as **b a d**

Comment: Your specifications are hard to follow. Could you revisit them and try to explain once again.

Comment: Why are the tags [visual-c++] and especially [objective-c++] present?

Comment: Presumably to cast the widest possible net, as this code would compile in either of those environments. :) It wouldn't be *valid* for either, but both VC++ and GCC would allow it.

Comment: @xanatos i initialize at 0 so yes 10 is ok when i run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were asked to create a random 2D array and then find the max:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int maxArray(int arr[][10], int rcap, int ccap ){
    int max = 0;
    for (int r=0; r < rcap; r++)
        for(int c=0; c < ccap; c++)
            if(arr[r][c] > max) max = arr[r][c];

    return max;
}

int main() {
    int a[10][10];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int r=0; r < 10; r++)
        for(int c=0; c < 10; c++)
            a[r][c] = (rand()%100); // make a random array
    cout << maxArray (a,10,10) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was the part that i was not sure about. where to rand()%100. i will tweak it a little to get what i want now. this pointed me in the right direction. thanks